# Set timezone when using strftime()

Tags: php, date, datetime

I´m having some problems showing the correct timezone offset when translating a datetime object with [strftime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

This is the object I´m working with (name: `$match_dateobject`) :

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2014-09-17 10:45:00
    [timezone_type] => 1
    [timezone] => -08:00
)
```

I want to show this in the following format, adjusted to Madrid´s timezone (GMT+2) and with Dutch day and month names: **"Wednesday 17 September 20:45"**

This works for the English version:

```
$match_dateobject->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Madrid'));
echo $match_dateobject->format('l j F H:i');

=> Result: Wednesday 17 September 20:45
```

But when I translate the day/month names with strftime(), the timezone is ignored:

```
$match_dateobject->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Madrid'));
$timestamp = $match_dateobject->format('U');
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'nl_NL.UTF-8');
echo strftime("%A %e %B %G %H:%M", $timestamp );

=> Result: woensdag 17 september 2014 18:45
```

Note that it´s showing the default GMT timezone, instead of Europe/Madrid (GMT+2).

Is there a way to set a timezone when working with strftime()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah,

```
 date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
```

Comment: What if I need to get the time in multiple timezone.

Comment: Then you use date_default_timezone_set() for each timezone.

Answer (score 1):

just add 1 function date_default_timezone_set(); in which pass the timezone  like "America/New_York" you can find out your timezone at https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_timezones.asp

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
echo strftime("%A %e %B %G %H:%M", time() );
```